# VNC clients don't work

Tags: remote-desktop, android, vnc, tightvnc

I tried lots of VNC clients , but they didn't work .

I figured out why , it's because when the client connects to the VNC server , the server takes no password .
A window pops up to the client that asks for the username and the password .

It's like RDP in windows , when the user types his username and password .

And I think that those VNC clients I tried don't support this kind of authentication . I

Programs I tried :
- vncviewer , shows : 
Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8 
< then it hangs >

- vinagre , blank window .
- krdc    , same .
- remmina , same .

I tried the android VNC Viewer (`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android`)

And it worked well !!

Just wondering if there is any method or any desktop client to do that .

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

**Solved by installing "Realvnc viewer" .**

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Glad you solved your problem, but could you expand your answer a bit to help others with a similar problem? Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/669195).  BTW, in 2 days, you will be able to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: You seem to have created 2 user accounts, [please look at this help page](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge them